# Looking for (nearly) worldwide elevation data

Tags: elevation, srtm, aster, tandem-x

I know the raw ASTER and SRTM datasets. Is there any error corrected version available? Or did anybody already combine the data? At least the ASTER data often misses tiles for costal regions (if there is only few elevation and the file would be nearly empty).

(I don't mind if I have to pay a fair price for it and it could even be just a web service where I get elevation data for a certain coordinate)

Jan

Comment: Have you looked at ASTER Global DEM V2?

Comment: Yes, as far as I understood there are still voids and it needs more post processing.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion both ASTER and SRTM are maxed out. Nothing can be computationally done to improve the data. ASTER just has too much noise and SRTM is just very rough data. If you are going to spend money I would get the data that ESA is acquiring right now:

There is a new data available here:

http://www.astrium-geo.com/en/66-geo-elevation-and-dem

You can find samples from different products here:

http://www.astrium-geo.com/en/23-sample-imagery

For a rough comparison of SRTM and the new data, this page is pretty nice:

http://www.astrium-geo.com/worlddem/

Read up on the mission:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TanDEM-X

http://www.dlr.de/rd/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-2440/3586_read-16692/

Comment: I've been asking for price and availability on the Astrium elevation for several months, "we haven't decided on price yet", so it's still just vapour ware, though I sure hope all that mist blows away soon! (+1 for aster and srtm are maxed out)

Answer (score 3):

An improved version of SRTM data can be obtained from http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/.

Coverage can be looked up under

http://www.viewfinderpanoramas.org/Coverage%20map%20viewfinderpanoramas_org3.htm

The creator has put special emphasis on manually filling the error on icy parts of the world as described here:

http://viewfinderpanoramas.org/topog.html

Disclaimer: I am not the author, and get no money for mentioning it!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what resolution you are looking for, I assume high.  But if you are wanting global coverage, you should looked at GTOPO30.  It is low resolution, but it is global coverage.

Comment: Well, not having spikes and holes is more important than resolution I'd say. The ASTER raw data is too rough i'd say. Pixel-resolution is maybe not the perfect measurement.

Comment: Can you give us more information what your size-definition of spike and hole is. GTOPO30 has one data point every km. If your working at a 10m scale on shoreline-hiking-trails that would put a lot of trails into the ocean.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the patched SRTM DEM from CGIAR:

http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/

Although it still contains the same intrinsic errors and limitations in coverage as SRTM, it is at least void-filled.

Answer (score 1):

If you need Europe, just look for the EU-DEM, a new product that is a fused version of ASTER DEM and SRTM.

http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/gisco_Geographical_information_maps/geodata/digital_elevation_model/eu_dem_laea

http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eu-dem

Comment: I looked at this for a while and I think that it almost has no difference to SRTM. Maybe the computation improved it by a few percent, but that is below detection limit in GIS.

Comment: It is much better than plain SRTM, especially in the Apls. See also http://courses.neteler.org/eu-dem-new-digital-surface-model-at-25m/